# React Function return nothing

Tags: reactjs, return-value

I am trying to get Display Name getUserinfo() based on a User ID getList()
I have attempted

- to use a variable to catch the data and feed to getList().
- to use state variables to setState and pass data to getList(). but it seems State is asynchronous, so it failed

Problem: why my getUserinfo() cannot return a value for getList() to use ?

```
 private getUserinfo(userid: number) {
    var result;
    let url;
    url = `/_api/web/GetUserById(${userid})`;
    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    };

    this.props.spHttpClient
      .get(
        this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + url,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        opt
      )
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((json: any) => {
          if (json.Title) {
            let name = json.Title;
            let email = json.Email;
            let issiteadmin = json.IsSiteAdmin;

            //debugger;
            return name;  // this has value but it returns nothing in another function I called
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

```
private getList() {
    this.state.data.length = 0;
    const qurl =
      "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list')/items?$select=*&$orderby=Modified desc";

    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    };

    this.props.spHttpClient
      .get(
        this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        opt
      )
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((json: any) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < json.value.length; i++) {

            let authorid = json.value[i].AuthorId;
            let editorid = json.value[i].Editorid;
            let Authorname = this.getUserinfo(authorid);
            let Editorname = this.getUserinfo(editorid);

            debugger;

            this.setState({
              data: [
                ...this.state.data,
                {

                  Authorname,
                  Editorname
                }
              ]
            });
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Explain what you mean by "but it seems State is asynchronous, so it failed". You're using `.then()` so your already in the async world.

Comment: I used return this.setState({Getname:name}) in the getUserinfo()
and in the getList() I could not get the value of this.state.Getname

so in the getList()
this.getUserinfo(authorid);
let Authorname = this.state.Getname;
and Authorname is undefined.

Comment: If you set state, you wouldn't want to return like that. You would just have access to the updated state later on.

Comment: How can I return value from a promise and pass it to another promise ?

Comment: @BrianThompson is right and by the way getUserInfo returns nothing. (see: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises))

Comment: How can I do that @Flui ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have not returned anything from `getUserInfo`, you had just called `this.props.spHttpClient.get()` without returning its value, for instance:

```
private getUserinfo(userid: number) {
  ...
  return this.props.spHttpClient.get( ... )
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      return response.json().then((json: any) => {
        if (json.Title) {
          let name = json.Title;
          let email = json.Email;
          let issiteadmin = json.IsSiteAdmin;
          return name;  // this has value but it returns nothing in another function I called
        }
      });
  });
}
```

This way, when you call `this.getUserinfo(authorid)` you will get a promise and you can use its value as follows:

```
 this.getUserinfo(authorid).then( name => {
    // use its name
 });
```

Comment: Jaime, Thanks for your prompt reply, the variable name shows undefine

Comment: Are you returning: return this.props.spHttpClient.get( ... ) ?

Comment: have you checked what response and json variables content are? By this I mean to check the response content and verify the properties it has.

Comment: for values in the getUserinfo , there are values in the name but in the getList() its is undefined.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU7Ek.png

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I have edited to show the final working example of my code

Answer (score 3):

This is how you would write it using async/await which improves the readability

```js
private async getUserinfo(userid: number) {
    var result;
    let url;
    url = `/_api/web/GetUserById(${userid})`;
    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    };

    const response: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.props.spHttpClient
      .get(
        this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + url,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        opt
      )
    const json = await response.json();

    if (json.Title) {
      let name = json.Title;
      let email = json.Email;
      let issiteadmin = json.IsSiteAdmin;

      //debugger;
      return name;  // this has value but it returns nothing in another function I called
    }
  }
```

You can aply the same style to getList